# ssis error when click on mapping

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

Using SQL Server 2005

Trying to copy a `.CSV` file to database with

> Error at UploadCSV [Connection manager "SERVER.DATABASE.USER_ID"]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E4D.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Native Client"  Hresult: 0x80040E4D  Description: "Login failed for user 'USER_ID'.".
>
> Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Destination [594]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "SERVER.DATABASE.USER_ID" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.
>
> (Microsoft Visual Studio)
>
> Exception from HRESULT: 0xC020801C (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap)
>
> Program Location:
>
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.CManagedComponentWrapperClass.AcquireConnections(Object pTransaction)
>   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.PipelineUtils.AcquireConnections(IDTSComponentMetaData90 componentMetadata, Connections connections, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
>   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.DataFlowUI.DataFlowComponentUI.AcquireConnections()
>   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.DataFlowUI.DataFlowComponentUI.ReinitializeMetadata()
>   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.DataFlowUI.DataFlowAdapterUI.connectionPage_SaveConnectionAttributes(Object sender, ConnectionAttributesEventArgs args)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the connection manager "Server.database.user_id" and click on test connection. You may need to enter password again depending upon security setting of the package.

Once the test connection is successful, you should not see this error while mapping columns in your destination.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this issue occurred when we are using a `VPN Server` (`SQL Server`) in our  **SSIS Package** as a connection manager.

So first of all try to login `SQL Server` with the same user at where you created your package (Local or on your machine).